# need to select max 2 rows but based on value

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I need to make a small adjustment here and not sure if it can be done. In the following, if there is no '001' row, then I only want 1 row for that order, but when there is 001 i do want that and the next one according to earliest time.

```
CREATE VIEW rklib.clspaytp AS Select * from
 (
     Select x.*,
     row_number() over (partition by otord#
                        order by case ottrnc when '001' then 1 else 2 end
                        , ottrnd, ottrt
                        )
                     as RowN
    from rklib.clspaytpp x
) a
 where a.RowN in (1,2)
```

We have data as such:

```
+-------+-------+------+------+
| Order | Codes | Rep  | Time |
+=======+=======+======+======+
| 123   | 001   | Buck | 0900 |
+-------+-------+------+------+
| 123   | CCW   | BUCK | 0909 |
+-------+-------+------+------+
| 123   | FGH   | BUCK | 0904 |
+-------+-------+------+------+
```

Here we want the  001 and the FGH. FGH is earlier than CCW by 5 mnts.

Now if the 001 was not there then all we want is the FGH, out of the 2. We only want a 2fer when one of these is the 001.

Comment: Please edit your question and show a sample of the input data, and an example of the end result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.

```
create table clspaytpp (
  otord# decimal (5, 0), 
  ottrnc char (3), 
  ottrnd char (10), 
  ottrt decimal (4, 0));

insert into clspaytpp values
(123, '001', 'Buck', 0900),
(123, 'CCW', 'BUCK', 0909),
(123, 'FGH', 'BUCK', 0904);

insert into clspaytpp values
(124, 'CCW', 'BUCK', 0909),
(124, 'FGH', 'BUCK', 0904);

with code1 as (
  select otord# as otord1
  from clspaytpp 
  where ottrnc = '001'
  group by otord#
  order by otord#)
select * 
from clspaytpp 
where otord# in (select otord1 from code1)
  and ottrnc = '001'
union
select * 
from clspaytpp o
where ottrt in (select min(ottrt) from clspaytpp i where i.otord# = o.otord# and ottrnc <> '001')
  and ottrnc <> '001'
order by 1, 2;
```